# What determines the direction a river takes in Alpha Centauri?

Tags: alpha-centauri

A river can never flow upwards, of course. But if there are multiple squares that the river could flow into, how does the game choose one?

Comment: I would check all surrounding squares for actual altitude. If you have one at 112 feet and another at 108 feet I would assume the river will flow to the lowest surrounding square. Need to check this myself to see if my assumption is correct.

Comment: @MarkRipley, this must be the correct answer if confirmed.

Comment: I recommend to raise the terrain to maximum level before drilling to aquifer, so as to achieve maximum river length. Drilling on flat surfaces tends to produce short rivers.  If I drill on the peak of a mountain, the river direction seems random. If I drill on the side, I agree with @MarkRipley; it seems that they have modelled real life pretty well, and gravity prevails. Note that there are certain terrains/improvements that a river won't flow though - I have never seen one through a borehole.

Comment: In addition, while you may not drill to aquifer next to an existing river, you ***can*** set multiple adjacent former to all drill to aquifer, which is what I do. First, raise a very tall mountain, then let rives cascade down all sides of it.